# Removing or Adding views vs ViewStub

Tags: android, layout, view, viewstub

What is the difference between .remove() .addView() and using ViewStub? How ViewStub increasing layout render efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html), when you use `ViewStub`, the layout that you `<include />` inside the stub won't be inflated unless required (setting the visibility of the stub to `VISIBLE` or calling `show()`).
The advantage is, none of the included view will be part of the view hierarchy, so your view is lighter.

See this example:
ViewStub not inflated:
[image]

After inflating:
[image]

Of course you have a tradeoff here, when you set VISIBLE (or show()) a reinflate (only on the ViewStub layout) happens.

Comment: thanks your answer. I found this article too. What happens if i remove() a view and .addView() dynamically. It is removing the memory too when remove instead of using ViewStub. Is it the same think or not?

Comment: You are correct, it does remove the entire view from memory. The problem is the performance of adding and removing a View, it is a costly operation. That's why Google created the ViewStub, it is lighter because you are just inflating a part of the view hierarchy, not all of it.

Comment: thanks for all. [Leonardo Ferrari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1232131/leonardo-ferrari)

Comment: Sure, glad I could help !

Comment: hello, I know this is old but what are the performance tradeoffs here? Reason I ask is I have a co-worker that wants me to change my implementation to not use viewstubs but rather remove/add views dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

ViewStub is the same as adding View in term of performance. Take a look at the ViewStub.inflate(). What it does is the adding view dynamically.

```
public View inflate() {
    ...
    final View view = factory.inflate(mLayoutResource, parent,
            false);
    ... 
    parent.addView(view, index, layoutParams);
    } else {
        parent.addView(view, index);
    }
    ...
    return view;
}
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/ViewStub.java